# What does 16x256 DRAM structure mean?

Tags: memory, ramdisk

I want to understand the difference between the DRAM structures 16x256 and 8x512 RAM indicates?

I have read on many rams stating 16x256, 8x512 1x4G , which one is better and in what ways. I am thinking to buy these for a 2gen Intel i3 Laptop.

I Googled and I found many of my RAM related queries but this remains unsolved.

And what is buffered and unbuffered RAM?

Answer (score 0):

I have learned this the VERY hard way 16X256MB or 8X512MB refers to the number of actual memory chips on the stick.  Almost nowhere do you find that much details in the specs.

I was looking for 4GB PC3-10600 (DDR3 1333mHz) DIMM Unbuffered non-ECC DDR3 SDRAM for an HP NV469UT#ABA Business Desktop Pro 6000 Small Form Factor.  I ordered memory three times to discover that as soon as I powered up the machine, I got 5 beeps and no boot - HP code for a memory error.

I stumbled across memory that would work in a local PC shop.  The difference?  All the memory I had ordered matched the specs for the machine exactly, but had only 8 memory chips on one side, none on the other (8X512).  The one that worked had 16 chips, 8 on each side (16X256).

No one anywhere knew their memory would not work until I talked to a tech at Crucial Memory.  He said the memory I had ordered was high-density and I needed non-high-density.  Crucial was the brand that worked.  Unfortunately, they no longer manufacture that configuration.

The other party that knew was a tech at Edge Memory.  He is the one who defined high-density (8X512) vs non-high-density (16X256).

I hope this information prevents someone else from experiencing the frustration and loss of time/revenue I lost on this deal.

Answer (score 0):

It refers to the density of the DRAM. This only matters as it relates to the motherboard. Some motherboards cannot accept the higher density.

256x16 = 4096Mb which = 512MB 
512x8 also = 4096Mb = 512MB

If one piece of RAM had 8 DRAMs on it, the 1st would only come to 4GB while the 2nd would be 8GB. But if the motherboard won't accept 512x8 density, you're stuck with the max RAM capacity of however many chips will fit.

Answer (score -1):

So i think you are referring to 1x4GB or 16x256MB correct? If so I believe you are looking at listings maybe on ebay or something. This would indicate the number of chips they have and size of memory. So in 1x4GB that would be 4GB in 1 chip. Usually in a standard PC you would have 4 slots for Ram (ususally 2 in laptops) so the only confusing thing is the 16*256 and 8*512 unless they are selling these in lots. Like 8 chips of 512MB Ram.

As far as buffered and unbuffered Ram, Your PC should tell you what kind to use, it will be unbuffered.

buffered/registered ram has a control chip built into the ram chip help the memory controller deal with large quantities of ram. you want to avoid buffered ram for a gaming computer (the extra controller chip adds latency). as stated it is for servers and workstations. Hope this helps.

I would just go to < http://www.crucial.com/ > and put in your make and model, they will tell you what Ram to buy (even if you dont get it from them) you can look those specs up with a different company.